A black screen (idle frame) appearing for 1/2 seconds before a DRM Video
I am using DashJS to play a playlist(list of videos). When the video plays, or it transitions from one video to the next video, the following issues happen :
A black screen appears for 1/2 seconds before the video starts playing.
Sometimes, the video does not start playing from the 0th second, and starts from a random second.
Sometimes, the video plays the video till the 1st second, goes back to 0, and starts playing again, giving a double play effect in the beginning.
I wish for neither of this to happen. My requirement is to play videos seamlessly with no lag, no black screen, no audio glitches, and always start from the beginning of the video. This requirement is being satisfied for when the video is not a DRM Video, but if it is a DRM Video, the above stated issues pop up. I request your assistance in fixing the same.
Code :
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1saOBon2wJYAsJgliA5VR_Cbx4flHTKj5tZLg4HPMLMU/edit?usp=sharing
Navigating the code : VideoPlayer.jsx makes use of StreamStackItem.jsx which makes use of DashPlayer.jsx
